# How can I delete all items but one in a players inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map where a player has a diamond chestplate named "Heros Chestplate" and I was wondering if there is a command out there that deletes all items in a player's inventory but that item? I'm currently in 1.8.8 and 
I'm using the command   `/clear @a !minecraft:diamond_chestplate 1 0 {display:{Name:"Hero's Chestplate"},ench:[{id:34,lvl:150}]}`

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you could do is clear the player's inventory and give them a new hero chestplate

```
/clear @a
/give @a minecraft:diamond_chestplate 1 0 {display:{Name:"Hero's Chestplate"},ench:[{id:34,lvl:150}]}
```